# flot in php for multiple datasets

Tags: php, json, flot

I am having the data as :

> $data1 = array([1341354816000, 1], [ 1341358185000, 2] , [
>   1341361620000, 3] , [ 1341538421000, 4] , [ 1341621724000, 5] , [
>   1341868470000, 6] , [ 1342133445000, 7] , [ 1342645937000, 8] , [
>   1342651985000, 9] , [ 1342744374000, 10] , [ 1343151552000, 11] , [
>   1343285910000, 12] , [ 1343286178000, 13] , [ 1343288137000, 14] , [
>   1343307010000, 15] , [ 1343307401000, 16] , [ 1343625187000, 17] , [
>   1343648616000, 18] , [ 1343649176000, 19] , [ 1343649567000, 20] , [
>   1343649898000, 21] , [ 1343867245000, 22] , [ 1343938551000, 23] , [
>   1343938916000, 24] , [ 1343939382000, 25] , [ 1344041570000, 26] , [
>   1344051059000, 27] , [ 1344235565000, 28] , [ 1344236000000, 29] , [
>   1344248074000, 30] );

---

> $data2 = array([1341354816000, 1], [ 1341358185000, 2] , [
>   1341361620000, 3] , [ 1342133445000, 4] , [ 1342645937000, 5] , [
>   1342651985000, 6] , [ 1342744374000, 7] , [ 1343286178000, 8] , [
>   1343288137000, 9] , [ 1343307010000, 10] , [ 1343307401000, 11] , [
>   1343625187000, 12] , [ 1343867245000, 13] , [ 1343938551000, 14] , [
>   1343938916000, 15] , [ 1343939382000, 16] , [ 1344041570000, 17] , [
>   1344051059000, 18] , [ 1344248074000, 19] , [ 1344322547000, 20] , [
>   1344330089000, 21] , [ 1344360922000, 22] , [ 1344405113000, 23] , [
>   1344445006000, 24] , [ 1344447855000, 25] , [ 1344479054000, 26] );

---

> $data3 = array([1341354816000, 1], [ 1341358185000, 2] , [
>   1341361620000, 3] , [ 1341538421000, 4] , [ 1341621724000, 5] , [
>   1342133445000, 6] , [ 1342645937000, 7] , [ 1342651985000, 8] , [
>   1342744374000, 9] , [ 1343286178000, 10] , [ 1343288137000, 11] , [
>   1343307010000, 12] , [ 1343307401000, 13] , [ 1343625187000, 14] , [
>   1343867245000, 15] , [ 1343938551000, 16] , [ 1343938916000, 17] , [
>   1343939382000, 18] );

Now i have to plot these data into the plot same as Turning series ON/OFF example.

can anyone help for this code in php.

I had created this list from different sql tables and php, so if the continuation code in php then it will helpful.

I had tried to add that data into the dataset :

`var datasets = { "all": { label: "All", data : '$data1' }, "resolved": { label: "Resolved", data : '$data2' }, "closed": { label: "Closed", data : '$data3' } };`

which is not working

Comment: Welcome to SO. These kinds of questions are not really suitable to answer; narrow it down to something specific that you want to know or tell us what you have tried and we can help you.

Comment: I am not able to add the data into the datasets and not able to plot the data. Or i want to know the procedure to add the data already there into datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Example of adding data, plotting and turning on/off- http://jsfiddle.net/zxtFc/3/

```
var DataSet1 = [ 
[1341354816000, 1], [ 1341358185000, 2] , [ 1341361620000, 3] , [ 1341538421000, 4] , [    1341621724000, 5] , [ 1341868470000, 6] , [ 1342133445000, 7] , [ 1342645937000, 8] , [ 1342651985000, 9] , [ 1342744374000, 10] , [ 1343151552000, 11] , [ 1343285910000, 12] , [ 1343286178000, 13] , [ 1343288137000, 14] , [ 1343307010000, 15] , [ 1343307401000, 16] , [ 1343625187000, 17] , [ 1343648616000, 18] , [ 1343649176000, 19] , [ 1343649567000, 20] , [ 1343649898000, 21] , [ 1343867245000, 22] , [ 1343938551000, 23] , [ 1343938916000, 24] , [ 1343939382000, 25] , [ 1344041570000, 26] , [ 1344051059000, 27] , [ 1344235565000, 28] , [ 1344236000000, 29] , [ 1344248074000, 30]
];
```